# In C++, why should the custom comparison function cmp be static when using sort() in a class?

Tags: c++

I want to use the custom comparison function cmp of sort() in the class. Why should it be defined as a static type? The code show as below:

```
class A{
public:
    // bool cmp(vector<int>& a,vector<int>& b){  // this does not compile
    static bool cmp(vector<int>& a,vector<int>& b){
        return a[0]<b[0];
    }

    vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),cmp);
        /* other code */
    }
};
```

I tried using the non-static cmp function, and an error occurred:

> error: reference to non-static member function must be called
> sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),cmp);

Comment: Non-static member functions require an instance of the class to call them. They are not interchangeable with static or free functions.

Comment: Even if you call `std::sort` inside a member function, the ordering function must still be a a function that can be called without an instance of an object. That means it must either be declare in a namespace scope (like a global or other non-member function) or be a static member function.

Comment: For your specific case I would rather recommend a [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead. As in `[](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a[0] < b[0]; }`. If argument auto-deduction is not possible (your compiler is too old, or you're forced to use an older standard version) then use the explicit type like you currently do with your function.

Comment: Presume you have `struct Foo { void print() {}; };`.  How would you call `print()` without an instance of `Foo`?

Comment: Show the code that **didn't** work.

Comment: It does not have to be static, it could be any old function unrelated to your class, but what it cannot be is a member function. Member functions require objects, a member function is called on a particular object. Look at your code, how could `std::sort` know which `A` object to use? There is no `A` object being passed as a parameter to `std::sort`.

Comment: So I can use `std::sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end(), A()::cmp);,` if cmp is defined as a member function, use an anonymous object of class A to call the cmp member function. Or it can't be used this way at all, and as the comments say, using anonymous functions is more recommended?

Comment: I don't agree with most of the comments above. The questions is clear as-is, even though the answer is quite trivial for anyone with experience in C++. And the answer is: "because you need an instance of `class A` to call `cmp`". Everything else like "you can't", or "only free functions are allowed" is simply wrong.

Comment: @pptaszni You can *wrap* a non-static member function in an object, but you can't use the member directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use non-static member function, if you need it for whatever reason (e.g. virtual dispatch). Just bind it to your instance:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> merge(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& intervals) {
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::sort(intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),std::bind(&A::cmp, this, _1, _2));
    /* other code */
}
```

You can achieve the same effect with lambda:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> merge(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& intervals) {
    std::sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), [this](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return cmp(lhs, rhs); });
    /* other code */
}
```